# .Net 5.0 - Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'HandshakeFailure

Tags: .net-5, windows-server-2012-r2, sslhandshakeexception

I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 on my production server. I upgraded my webapplication to .Net 5.0 from 4.5. Now randomly facing this error, while communication of my front-end applications with the backend REST API built on .Net 5.0:

> Exception[System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The
> SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)
> ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert:
> 'HandshakeFailure'.
> ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I have already used the below lines of code in my app:

```
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
```

Comment: Di you get an answer to this?

Comment: no didnt get answer. I came to the conclusion that probably there is some conflict between the OS (Windows Server 2012) and .Net 6.0. Some people have reported the same on various forums

Comment: In the end I was forced to put code on a 2019 server. However when looking at `IIS Crypto` it may be down to some ciphers begin removed. As its a live server I cant reboot it multiple times to find the right ones!